# Is there a generalized version of scale_fill_distiller and scale_colour_distiller?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I do different plots with `ggplot2` and want them all to have the same colour. The thing is that I use different `geom`s that sometimes work with `fill` and sometimes with `col`. See here:

```
df <- data.frame(x= 1:10, y= 1:10, col= c(1:5, 5:1))
library(ggplot2)
gg1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, group= x, fill= col)) +
  geom_bar()
gg2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col= col)) +
  geom_point()
```

If I want both `ggplot2` objects to have the same colour palette, say `Spectral`, I would need to do `gg1 + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")` and `gg2 + scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Spectral")`. Pay attention to the difference "scale_**fill**_distiller" and "scale_**colour**_distiller". If we mix this up, the plot changes.

I have many plots and do not instantly know whether a `col` or `fill` was used, i.e. I have to manually print the plot before I can actually add the palette. So the question is whether there is a generalized function which adds a colour palette to any `col`, `fill`, whatever easthetic. So the function is suppost for `gg1` and `gg2` like this: `gg1 + scale_generalized_distiller(palette = "Spectral")` and `gg2 + scale_generalized_distiller(palette = "Spectral")`

---

**What I do so far**:

I simpy add all whats possible. Like this:

```
gg1  +
  scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
gg2 +
  scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

I hope there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `aesthetics` parameter, either with `scale_color_distiller` or `scale_fill_distiller`:

```r
gg1  +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral", aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))

gg2 +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral", aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))
```

Checks

```r
ggFill1 <- gg1  +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))
ggColor1 <- gg1 +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral", aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))
all.equal(ggFill1,ggColor1)
# [1] TRUE

ggFill2 <- gg2  +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))
ggColor2 <- gg2  +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral", aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))
all.equal(ggFill2,ggColor2)
# [1] TRUE
```